# How to uninstall metrics package in Atom.io editor?

Tags: atom-editor

The Atom.io Github page for the metrics package describes how to *disable* the metrics package:

> ## Metrics package
>
> A package that reports usage information to Google Analytics.
>
> If you do not want this information reported, you can disable this
> package. Open the Settings View by running the Settings View: Open
> command from the Command Palette, go to the Packages section, and then
> find and disable the Metrics package.
>
> https://github.com/atom/metrics

I do, though, want to uninstall it completely. `Atom.io -> Settings -> Packages` offers two buttons: `Uninstall` and `Enable/Disable`.

When I click `Uninstall`, nothing seems to happen.

So how do I get rid of the metrics package completely? And why is the uninstall button not doing its job?

Note: I am trying this on MacOS X. Haven't counterchecked on Windows yet. Can someone check on Windows?

## Edit:

It seems the authors have removed the uninstall button for this package in the latest version (1.0.2). So how does one get rid of this unwanted package? I don't trust "disabling" it.

Comment: I'm not the only one who strongly dislikes the existence of this package in open source software: https://discuss.atom.io/t/collecting-metrics-in-atom-core/14178